# Update based on Row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, row-number

Please consider this table:

```
id       Col1         Col2
--------------------------
1        nima         null
18       john         null
25       sara         null
```

I have a select that retutn this records:

```
id         Col
---------------
1          LA
2          WA
3          FL
```

I want to update this record on above table with same order that you see.for example update `LA` for `nima` and...

How I can do this?

thanks

Comment: How do you determine the order of the second query?

Comment: For example with ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: there is no guaranteed row order in sql server, you need a column to order by, or a key

Comment: ok I got it.I'll edit my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update based on `row_number()` and the fact that you can update [common table expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in SQL Server, like this:

```
with cte1 as (
   select Col2, row_number() over(order by id) as rn
   from Table1
), cte2 as (
   select col, row_number() over(order by id) as rn
   from Table2
)
update c1 set
    Col2 = c2.col
from cte1 as c1
    left outer join cte2 as c2 on c2.rn = c1.rn
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92d5e/1)</kbd>**

Note that if your tables are large, the performance could be not very good. If this is the case, you can think about creating temporary tables with row_number columns and make this columns primary key of just create appropriate indexes

Comment: Thanks dear @Roman.This works.Can ypu please explain this statement? I don't understand how we can update a CTE? CTE is a record set that can return from multiple table

Comment: well you can update simple CTE, as far as I know, SQL Servers just treats them as updateable view - see the section about updateable views here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx